# Array update in state via reducer

Tags: reactjs

I am building a quiz app and I want to remove two incorrect answers from an array of questions (if a user chooses 50/50 help).
The problem is that I end up modifying my original array "questions". so if the user click on buttons play again, and the first question is loaded, it has only two answers now (as the two were eliminated when the user chose 50/50.

I thought that cloning the array  let newArrr = [...state.questions] would solve this problem, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

```
case REMOVE_TWO_INCORRECT_ANSWERS:
  let newArrr = [...state.questions];
  const correctAnswerIndex = state.questions[
    state.currentPage
  ].answers.findIndex((answer) => answer.correct === true);
  let randomNr = Math.ceil(
    Math.random() * state.questions[state.currentPage].answers.length - 1
  );
  if (
    randomNr === correctAnswerIndex &&
    randomNr === state.questions[state.currentPage].answers.length
  ) {
    randomNr--;
  }
  if (randomNr === correctAnswerIndex && randomNr === 0) {
    randomNr++;
  }
  let answers = [
    state.questions[state.currentPage].answers[correctAnswerIndex],
    state.questions[state.currentPage].answers[randomNr],
  ];
  newArrr[state.currentPage].answers = answers;
  return {
    ...state,
    questions: newArrr,
    helpRemoveAnswersUsed: true,
  };

//questions from my local data.js
    case SET_QUESTIONS_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, loading: false, questions: payload };
```

Comment: Are you using a callback argument for the `setState` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newArrr = [...state.questions]` does indeed create a new array. The problem is that array contains references to all of the same objects as in the original. So when you do `newArrr[state.currentPage].answers = answers;`, you modify the object at `newArrr[state.currentPage]` which is the same object as in the original array.

This is what is called a "shallow copy". To do what you want you need to do a deep copy. In other words, you also need to clone each question object...and each object it stores...and the objects those store...etc. There are already solutions on Stack Overflow and else where how to do this. So feel free to google it.

Comment: Thank you! That helped.
This solution worked `let newArrr = state.questions.map((item) => { return { ...item }; });`